# How to find if Shapely LineString is complex (i.e. self-intersects)

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

Either I'm missing something - I can't see it in the docs - or it's not built-in to Shapely: how do I determine if a LineString is complex, i.e. self-intersects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's base class `class shapely.geometry.base.BaseGeometry` has an option `is_simple`, which says

> True if the geometry is simple, meaning that any self-intersections
>   are only at boundary points, else False

http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.geometry.html#shapely.geometry.base.BaseGeometry

```
line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1)])
line.is_simple
```

Comment: Ah, in that deeper bit of the documentation which I didn't find. Thanks!